# Google Chrome Extension - Help needed

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Im new on **Google Chrome Extensions** coding, and i have some basic questions.

I want to make a Chrome Extension, and the scheme is the following:

-a popup window, containing buttons and result fields (popup.html)

-when a button is clicked, i want to trigger an event, this event should connect to a webserver (i make the servlet too), and gather information from the server. (XMLHttpRequest())

-after that, i want my extension to load the gathered information into one of the result fields.

Simple, isn't it? But i have several problems, right at the beginning:( I started developing with reading tutorials, but i have fog on the main structure of an extension. Now, i started an app, containing a popup.html, manifest.json ...
In popup.html theres a result field, and a button

```
<div id="extension_container">
<div id="header">
    <p id="intro">Result here</p>
    <button type="button" id="button">Click Me!</button>
</div> <!-- END header -->
<div id="content">

</div> <!-- END content -->
```

When button is clicked, i trigger an event, handeled with jquery, code here:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button").click(function(){
            $("#intro").text("Hello, im added");
            alert("Clicked");
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here comes the problem, in popup.html this doesnt work, if i load it to Chrome, nothing happens. Otherwise, if i open popup.html in browser, not as an extension, everything works fine. So, i think i have basic misunderstandings on extension structures, starting with background pages, background javascript and so on.. :( Could anyone help me?

Comment: I'not sure... but if I remember well is important where you put your <script> tag to open the popup. Did you try putting the js code in a file and link it in the main html page? Did you receive security errors?

Comment: If i open popup.html (note: script and html is here too) with chrome directly, everything works fine, event triggered, and the text is shown, as pretended, but if i load my extension to chrome with chrome://extensions -> "load unpacked apps", and open popup.html nothing happens :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing in Chrome 19.0.1084.1 this worked for me....

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="extension_container">
        <div id="header">
            <p id="intro">Result here</p>
            <button type="button" id="button">Click Me!</button>
        </div> <!-- END header -->
        <div id="content">
        </div> <!-- END content -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        $("#intro").text("Hello, im added");
        alert("Clicked");
    });
});
```

**Possible Error**
I think what MIGHT be your problem is that you have "manifest_version" : 2 in your manifest and your popup.html looks something like this....

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--script src="popup.js"></script-->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#button").click(function() {
            $("#intro").text("Hello, im added");
            alert("Clicked");
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="extension_container">
        <div id="header">
            <p id="intro">Result here</p>
            <button type="button" id="button">Click Me!</button>
        </div> <!-- END header -->
        <div id="content">
        </div> <!-- END content -->
     </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

...this wouldnt work because inline scripts arent allowed in manifest version 2.

Comment: Thanks PAEz, you have earned my respect, becouse this was the problem, i had "manifest version 2" in my manifest file, as soon as i changed it to 1, my script started to work correctly. Thanks again ;)

Comment: Thanks, PAEz!  Chrome now rejects a manifest version that isn't 2, but I have moved my script to a separate JS file and everything works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you added the jQuery library with an additional tag like this?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

After I did that, I had no more problems. Before I did it, I had an "$ is undefined" error, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i added two different ways, one was what you have written, and to be sure, i downloaded it to my library, and inserted into code 'directly'. :/