# Alert not appearing in popup.html of chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am still very new with chrome extensions and am just testing things out.
Right now I have a popup.html that with a short form that I want to create an alert when submit is clicked. I cannot for the life of me figure out why it's not working.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js">

</script>
</head>
<body onload="alert('open')">
<form>
Username: <input type='text' id="username" name='username'></input>
Password: <input type='password' id='password' />
          <button onclick="alert('test');return false;">Login</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Edit: I even made an onload in the body tag to see if an alert would open there but it doesn't. In the popup.js I have an alert open on window.onload and that works however.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function stops after you return false.
Put return false at the end of the statement, then your alert should work. Or you could take it out.

```
 <button onclick="alert('test')">Login</button>
```

*Update*
After some research I found out the following...

> Inline JavaScript will not be executed
>
> Inline JavaScript, as well as dangerous string-to-JavaScript methods like eval, will not > be executed. This restriction bans both inline  blocks and inline event handlers > (e.g. ).

[Source here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/contentSecurityPolicy.html#H3-1)

Comment: Hmm I changed that cause it makes sense but the alert is still not appearing. I even added an onLoad to the body to see if an alert would happen there but it didnt't :/

Comment: Make sure that you reload your extension when you make changes. You can find this by going to chrome://settings/extensions# in chrome and clicking on the name of the extension to expand for more options.

Comment: ah I see! Okay I moved everything into a seperate js file and use addeventlisteners and it worked perfectly. Thanks!!

Comment: Hey Eric, would you mind adding a little extra detail on how you solved the problem? Having the same problem here but i'm not sure how to go about adding an event listener.

Answer (score 4):

This could be your problem too: [inline scripts doesnt work with "manifest_version":2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9973209/1306083)

So, i tested, and with the following manifest, your code **works**!

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "test",
  "manifest_version":1,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/padlock.png",
    "default_popup":"html/popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", 
    "http://*/*"
  ]
}
```

Anyway.. it would be better to handle actions in popup.js, but first, change button attributes in popup.html to the following: `<button type="button">Login</button>`

*popup.js:*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":button").click(function(){
        alert("test");
        //more code here...
    });
});
```

Remember to insert jquery.js into your `<head>` tag, in *popup.html*, just above of *popup.js*:

```
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/popup.js"></script>
</head>
```

I wish, it was useful. Regards Jim..

Comment: Appreciate your efforts, but I tried changing `manifest_version` , doesn't seem to be working for me.